# vb code converted to c# compilation error

Tags: c#, vb.net

I had a code for getting the hdd id written in vb.net

Now I need to re-write the code into c#. I have converted the vb.net code to c# but it is not compiling.

Below is the vb.net code

```
Dim hdCollection As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

Dim searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

For Each wmi_HD As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
    Dim hd As HardDrive = New HardDrive()
    hd.Model = wmi_HD("Model").ToString()
    hd.Type = wmi_HD("InterfaceType").ToString()

    hdCollection.Add(hd)
Next wmi_HD
```

here is the converted C# code:

```
ArrayList hdCollection = new ArrayList();

              ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

              foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
              {

                  HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
                  hd.Model = wmi_HD("Model").ToString();
                  hd.Type = wmi_HD("InterfaceType").ToString();

                  hdCollection.Add(hd);
              }
```

Following is the error I am getting when compiling the c# code:

'wmi_HD' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VB code performs a subscript (indexed) access. In C#, this converts to a call to the `this[]` property. So the call needs square braces in C#:

```
hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
```

Apart from that, there’s one thing wrong with both codes: Do not use `ArrayList`, the type is obsolete. In fact, the same is true for (most of) the other types in the `System.Collections` namespace. The types have been replaced by generic classes in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

In your case, you want a `List<string>` instead of the `ArrayList` (or, in VB, `List(Of String)`).

Comment: Thanks. It was a silly mistake by me :] and also I have changed the ArrayList to List<T>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not converted the wmi_HD indexers properly.

Change these lines:

```
hd.Model = wmi_HD("Model").ToString();
hd.Type = wmi_HD("InterfaceType").ToString();
```

To:

```
hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
```

Square brackets, not round.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
```